# Child view doesn't stay centered within its parent when animating the width constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a container and centered children.

```
// Center constraint added to container
NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// Width constraint added to child
NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
```

After laying out all the views, their positions are correct. But when I start animating changes to the child's width, it loses its centered position and moves gradually back to it towards the end of the animation.

Here's the method I have as part of the child class to start the animation

```
  widthConstraint?.constant = widthNew
  UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
     self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
  }) { (completed: Bool) in
     if completed {
        print("done")
     }
  }
```

Here is the initial state, before I start animating.

[image]

This is when the jump happens and it loses its centering.

[image]

But towards completion, it move back into the center.

[image]

How do I make sure that it's always centered?

Comment: widthConstraint is your childView's constraint right ?

Comment: Yes, it is, I guess this behaviour is not standard.

Comment: Actually I tried to reproduce your animation right now. I guess you should change here: self.childView?.layoutIfNeeded() cause you are changing childView's constraints you should layoutChildView. When I tried like this it worked :)

Comment: I tried adding `self.layoutIfNeeded()` into the animation block, no effect :/

Comment: I actually manage to do it with customView also and I'll share the code but I guess your problem is about your view's constraints.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
        @IBOutlet weak var animatedView: UIView!

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        @IBAction func Btn1(sender: AnyObject) {

            widthConstraint?.constant = 20
            UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
                self.animatedView?.layoutIfNeeded()
                }) { (completed: Bool) in
                    if completed {
                        print("done")
                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

And the constraints are :

[image]
This is working code so could you try changing your views constraint outside of your view. Then we will get our problem.

## EDIT

I used this view as animated view just to see how it is when you set your own constraints inside your view.

```
public class AnimatedView: UIView {

    public var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public func animate()
    {
        widthConstraint?.constant = 20
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (completed: Bool) in
                if completed {
                    print("done")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Settings it's widthConstraint from its superview and trigger animating also from there. This is also working.